# Sort a dict by values, given that a key contains many values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a dict by values, where each of my keys have many values.
I know It is not possible to sort a dictionary, only to get a representation of a dictionary that is sorted. Dictionaries are inherently orderless.

I tried this solutions, from another post but it doesn't seem to work for my case :

> ```
> x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
> {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
> {0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2, 4: 3, 3: 4}
> ```

or

> ```
> dict(sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
> {0: 0, 2: 1, 1: 2, 4: 3, 3: 4}
> ```

from this post
[How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Also, I tried :

> `sorted(x, key=lambda x: x['key'])`

But, there my dict is a string and it doesn't work and It would not be the best option if I want to apply it in every keys, i would have to repeat the process for each of them.

Here is a sample of my dict :

```
{
'/Users/01': 
 ['V01File12.txt',
  'V01File01.txt',
  'V01File18.txt',
  'V01File15.txt',
  'V01File02.txt',
  'V01File11.txt' ] ,
 '/Users/02':
 ['V02File12.txt',
  'V02File01.txt',
  'V02File18.txt',
  'V02File15.txt',
  'V02File02.txt',
  'V02File11.txt' ]
}
```

and so on ...

the expected output would be :

```
{'/Users/01': 
 ['V01File01.txt',
  'V01File02.txt',
  'V01File11.txt',
  'V01File12.txt',
  'V01File15.txt',
  'V01File18.txt' ] ,
 '/Users/02': 
 ['V02File01.txt',
  'V02File02.txt',
  'V02File11.txt',
  'V02File12.txt',
  'V02File15.txt',
  'V02File18.txt' ] 
 }
```

Comment: What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: What is the goal here? I think there are more conceptual questions you need to ask.

Comment: The goal is to have the dict sorted by values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you're not trying to sort the dict, you're trying to sort the lists in it. I would just use a comprehension:

```
data = {k, sorted(v) for k, v in data.items()}
```

Or just alter the dict in place:

```
for v in data.values():
    v.sort()
```

Comment: If OP is okay with mutating the lists in the existing dict then perhaps: `for v in d.values(): v.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to sort the list inside each dictionary:**

```
a ={
'/Users/01': 
 ['V01File12.txt',
  'V01File01.txt',
  'V01File18.txt',
  'V01File15.txt',
  'V01File02.txt',
  'V01File11.txt' ] ,
 '/Users/02':
 ['V02File12.txt',
  'V02File01.txt',
  'V02File18.txt',
  'V02File15.txt',
  'V02File02.txt',
  'V02File11.txt' ]  


for i in a:
        a[i] = sorted(a[i])
```

Comment: Without making extra lists: `for v in a.values(): v.sort()`

Answer (score 1):

**The best solution is the solution of @StevenRumblaski:**

```
for b in a.values(): b.sort()
```